# React Router is leaving my main page loaded when trying to load other pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a MainPage that is loaded in App.js but when I use Browser Router and Route it will keep the MainPage and loads the second page over the top of it. Any tips would be helpful.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Mainpage></Mainpage> 
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The other thing that is weird is that it is loading the background of the page and styling that it is routing to when the button is not even pushed.
This is the main page.

```
class Mainpage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link exact to="/meettheteam">
                  This is a new Page
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
        <h1>
          THE
          <br />
          BARBER
          <br />
          SHOP
        </h1>
        <p>
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
          <img src={facebookLogo} alt="logoFacebook" />
          <img src={twitterLogo} alt="logoTwitter" />
          @TheBarberShop
        </p>
        <ul>
          <div className="schedule">
            <li>SCHEDULE</li>
          </div>
          <div className="styles">
            <li>STYLES</li>
          </div>
          <div className="meettheteam">
            <li>MEET THE TEAM</li>
          </div>
        </ul>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/meettheteam" component={MeetTheTeam} />
        </Switch>
        {/* <Route path="/stylesandprices" component={StylesAndPrices}/> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Mainpage;
```

Comment: `Mainpage` is rendered unconditionally in your `Router`, so it will *always* render. `MeetTheTeam` is rendered by a `Route` within a `Switch` so it will only render when `Mainpage` is rendered and the path is "/meettheteam". What you expect the behavior to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the navigation portion of your main page to always render (to obviously allow navigation) then I have the following suggestions:

1. Move the header/nav to `App` component and render at the top of the router.
2. Move the `Switch` also to `App` and render your `Mainpage` and other page components in their own respective `Route` components, in decreasing specificity, i.e. `"/pathA/b"` listed *before* `"/pathA"`.
3. Since the `Switch` matches and returns the ***first*** matching `Route` or `Redirect`, render the `Mainpage` route last as a default "home page".
4. If you want link highlighting (i.e. noticed the `exact` prop on the `Link`) then use `NavLink` as the `Link` component doesn't take this prop. Though, the `exact` prop here really only matters if you have nested routes that you don't want the link to appear active for

Changes

App

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <header>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/meettheteam">
                    This is a new Page
                  </Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </header>

          <Switch>
            <Route path="/meettheteam" component={MeetTheTeam} />
            <Route path="/stylesandprices" component={StylesAndPrices} />
            {/* other routes listing in decreasing specificity */}
            <Route component={Mainpage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Mainpage

```
class Mainpage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          THE
          <br />
          BARBER
          <br />
          SHOP
        </h1>
        <p>
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
          <img src={facebookLogo} alt="logoFacebook" />
          <img src={twitterLogo} alt="logoTwitter" />
          @TheBarberShop
        </p>
        <ul>
          <div className="schedule">
            <li>SCHEDULE</li>
          </div>
          <div className="styles">
            <li>STYLES</li>
          </div>
          <div className="meettheteam">
            <li>MEET THE TEAM</li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm talking about wrap routes inside of a `Switch` statement so it would not render on each other,  But this style is not Ideal for me because what if you also have another route that you would like to put on a different component? would you also define another `Switch` on that component? will if that you do that it will create the same Issue `Routes will render on top of each other`. This answer is a kind of different version of mine with a twist of adding the code snippets from the question, I commended your effort  so that's why I upvote.

Comment: @Rehan The subtle difference is I didn't say that rendering routes *outside* a `Switch` is wrong. The OP's issue is that the `Mainpage` component is still rendering content even though the URL is now on a sub-page, the solution is a bit of a refactor so *some* of the UI remains always, and *some* moved into *its* own route. I don't quite follow your question about "what if you also have another route that you would like to put on a different component?" Can you explain this a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Routes should be wrapped inside of a `<Switch>` component of react-router-dom

---

**Right usage:**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ComponentA from './componenta'
import ComponentB from './componentb'

function App() {

  return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <ComponentA />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/componentb">
            <ComponentB />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App
```

---

This example below would render first route and second route on top of each other, This is the similar way on how the code snippets of the question was structured. The first route was wrap with `Switch` while the second route was outside of `Switch`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ComponentA from './componenta'
import ComponentB from './componentb'

function App() {

  return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <ComponentA />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <ComponentB />
        </Route>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

**Tips/Suggestion:**

The best thing to do is to wrap all the `Route`'s with `Switch` statement at the top level of the app hierarchy

Comment: You most certainly can render a `Route` outside a `Switch` inside a `Router`, along with any other component. A `Router` renders routes inclusively whereas a `Switch` renders them exclusively.

Comment: @DrewReese true, but this the way to mitigate this specific scenario, If Route is not wrap with Switch they will both render on top of each other.

Comment: So your claim is incorrect. Also, there is only one route being rendered which is why everything not in a route inside the `Switch` is still rendered.

Comment: @DrewReese, it's a general Idea for this kind of problem, If you there is two routes it should be wrapped with `Switch` so it would not render on each other

Comment: @DrewReese, on the code snippets of this question the first route was place on a `Switch` while the second route was place outside that's what I mean. Though I see that it was commented out I still think that the question also mean for that commented route.

Comment: You could just as easily specify the `exact` prop on any route in a `Router` you want to exclusively render and get the same result. My point is that saying it is wrong to render routes outside a `Switch` is wrong, there are perfectly valid use cases for it.

Comment: @DrewReese, oh no, I'm not referring for that (`it is wrong to render routes outside a Switch`), But I'm suggesting that it would be best to wrap all of the `Routes` with a `Switch` on the top-level of the app hierarchy to mitigate the scenario.

Comment: Putting the switch with the routes directly under the hashrouter solved this issue for me, upvoted answer :)